# Multiple WebSeciurityConfig in one Spring application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml

We are maintaining two versions of our application from security perspective

```
1. SAML based spring security 
2. Spring and JDBC based application security.
```

As some of our customers already have SAML IDP (like ADFS and GLUU) which they want us to integrate for SSO  and some customer doesn't have SAML IDP.

Is there a way that both configurations can coexist and based on the customer using the application, security is imposed on the user.

**For ex:** if the request is coming for customer *a.myserverhost.com* SAML based security configurations are imposed. and if the request is form *b.myserverhost.com* the other webSeciurityConfig is imposed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, all of this is possible.  What I would suggest is implementing your own [AuthenticationManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/01579be7d42a0f7c0e75b35a50e46165c14f9c7f/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.java) which manages multiple [AuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/01579be7d42a0f7c0e75b35a50e46165c14f9c7f/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.java)s (e.g. SAML, JDBC).

That's where you can insert your conditional logic for choosing the correct provider based on certain criteria.

For inspiration, look at the default implementation [ProviderManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/01579be7d42a0f7c0e75b35a50e46165c14f9c7f/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.java).

Out of the box the ProviderManager will iterate over all of your AuthenticationProviders and attempt to authenticate the User.  If it doesn't find the User it moves on to the next one.  If that's all you need then you don't need any custom implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me find inspiration , will try to implement.
I believe after checking the URL  I would call the correct authentication provider using "auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());" in configure method of websecurityconfig

Comment: That method is part of an AuthenticationManagerBuilder and is where you register your AuthenticationProviders.  This isn't where you define the conditional logic.  You need to register both providers by calling the same method twice, authenticationProvider(saml()) and authenticationProvider(jdbc()).  Then inside your CustomAuthenticationManager you implement the authenticate() method and that's where you define your conditional logic.  Like I mentioned before, the default implementation, ProviderManager will iterate over each AuthenticationProvider until a successful Authentication is returned

Comment: ^ If that is sufficient for your use case then you don't need to bother with custom implementations at all.